# React Native : Is it possible (/how) to pass props to a class of static functions?

Tags: react-native

Normally when passing props, one would do something like:

```
var MyClass = require('./MyClass.js');
<MyClass Prop1={prop1} Prop2={prop2} />
```

These are then available in the `this.props` scope of the child component.

If I have a helper class that just has static functions in it. How would I pass props into the class? The declaration is simply

```
var MyHelperClass = require('./MyHelperClass.js');
```

The contents would be similar to

```
var MyHelperClass = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function(){
   return null;
  },
  statics: {
    functionOne: function(string){
      var returnObject = {};
      // do something with this.props..
      return returnObject;
    },
  },

  render: function() {}
});
```

For now I've created an initalise function that I call in componentDidMount that passes all of my data and function references down into the HelperClass but I'm curious.

Answer (score 0):

If `MyHelperClass` simply stores static functions and doesn't render anything, you could essentially create your own `store` for them.

Here's how I package my API calls:

```
var api = {

  getAllPosts: function(token, daysAgo) {
    daysAgo = daysAgo || 0;
    var requestObj = {
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token,
        'Host': 'api.producthunt.com'
      }
    };

    return fetch('https://api.producthunt.com/v1/posts?days_ago=' + daysAgo, requestObj)
      .then(function(res) {
        return res.json();
      })
  },
}
```

This is located in an `api.js` file, and contains just that object. I also call `module.exports = api` at the end, and `require` it in any components that need it. In those components, I can just call something like `api.getAllPosts(this.state.token, this.state.daysAgo)` and pass in my state/props as I please.

Comment: Thanks, I'm already doing something similar to that but I was trying to tidy up the code a little. The initialise works well and I can pass predefined blocks of functions in easily. I have multiple functions all wrapped up in one js file. I believe it was you that I was speaking regarding a background handler. That's what this is for. Queues up all my calls and fires them off sequentially.